# Quantum Phase Estimation on a superposed state

Tags: quantum-phase-estimation

Is it possible, using the QPE algorithm, to map the state $\sum_j\alpha_j\,\left|v_j\right\rangle\,|0\rangle^{\otimes n}$ to the state $\sum_j\alpha_j\,\left|v_j\right\rangle\,\left|\theta_j\right\rangle$? I understand how it is done, and why does it work when applying the QPE algorithm to an eigenvector $|v_i\rangle$. But there is this measurement after the inverse QFT, which will just outputs the state $\sum_j\alpha_j\,\left|v_j\right\rangle\,\left|\theta_k\right\rangle$ with probability $\left\|\alpha_k\right\|^2$.

I don't think it is possible to get such an entangled state after the measurement of a quantum register. Still, there are algorithms which use the QPE to get this entangled state, and which even uncomputes the second register once they're done with. What am I missing?

The algorithm I want to implement is designed as follows:

First, we have a quantum state $|\psi\rangle=\sum_j\alpha_j\,\left|v_j\right\rangle$. Then, we apply the QPE with a certain unitary whose eigenvectors are the $\left|v_i\right\rangle$ (this is not true in practice, there's an intermediary step but this does not matter here). Hence, we are left with the state $\sum_j\alpha_j\,\left|v_j\right\rangle\,\left|\theta_j\right\rangle$. We consider a gate $\mathbf{T}_\theta$ such that $\mathbf{T}_\theta\,\left|\theta_j\right\rangle\,|0\rangle = \left|\theta_j\right\rangle\,|1\rangle$ is $\theta_j < \theta$ and $\left|\theta_j\right\rangle\,|0\rangle$ if $\theta_j\geqslant\theta$. We apply this gate on the second register and are left with the state:

$$\sum_{j\in\mathcal{S}}\alpha_j\,\left|v_j\right\rangle\,\left|\theta_j\right\rangle\,|0\rangle + \sum_{j\in\overline{\mathcal{S}}}\alpha_j\,\left|v_j\right\rangle\,\left|\theta_j\right\rangle\,|1\rangle$$

where $\mathcal{S}$ represents the set of indexes $j$ such that $\theta_j\geqslant\theta$. We finally uncompute the QPE to get the state:

$$\sum_{j\in\mathcal{S}}\alpha_j\,\left|v_j\right\rangle\,|0\rangle + \sum_{j\in\overline{\mathcal{S}}}\alpha_j\,\left|v_j\right\rangle\,|1\rangle$$

and we measure the second register. This works well if all $\theta_j$ can be represented exactaly on $n$ qubits. Now, let us assume this is not the case. We denote $2^n\,\theta_j=\overline{\theta_j} + 2^n\,\delta_j$. After applying the QPE, we are left with the state:

$$\frac{1}{2^n}\,\sum_j\alpha_j\,\left|v_j\right\rangle\,\sum_{x=0}^{2^n-1}\sum_{k=0}^{2^n-1}\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{2\,\mathrm{i}\,\pi\,k}{2^n}\,\left(x-2^n\,\theta_j\right)}\,|x\rangle$$

which we can rewrite as:

$$\frac{1}{2^n}\,\sum_j\alpha_j\,\left|v_j\right\rangle\,\sum_{x=0}^{2^n-1}\sum_{k=0}^{2^n-1}\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{2\,\mathrm{i}\,\pi\,k}{2^n}\,\left(x-\overline{\theta_j}\right)}\,\mathrm{e}^{2\,\mathrm{i}\,\pi\,k\,\delta_j}\,|x\rangle$$

which we can also rewrite as:

$$\frac{1}{2^n}\,\sum_j\alpha_j\,\left|v_j\right\rangle\,\left(\sum_{k=0}^{2^n-1}\mathrm{e}^{2\,\mathrm{i}\,\pi\,k\,\delta_j}\,\left|\overline{\theta_j}\right\rangle+\sum_{\substack{x=0\\x\neq\overline{\theta_j}}}^{2^n-1}\sum_{k=0}^{2^n-1}\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{2\,\mathrm{i}\,\pi\,k}{2^n}\,\left(x-\overline{\theta_j}\right)}\,\mathrm{e}^{2\,\mathrm{i}\,\pi\,k\,\delta_j}\,|x\rangle\right)\,.$$

We now apply $\mathbf{T}_\theta$:

$$\frac{1}{2^n}\,\left[\sum_{j\in\mathcal{S}}\alpha_j\,\left|v_j\right\rangle\sum_{k=0}^{2^n-1}\mathrm{e}^{2\,\mathrm{i}\,\pi\,k\,\delta_j}\,\left|\overline{\theta_j}\right\rangle\,|0\rangle+\sum_{j\in\overline{\mathcal{S}}}\alpha_j\,\left|v_j\right\rangle\sum_{k=0}^{2^n-1}\mathrm{e}^{2\,\mathrm{i}\,\pi\,k\,\delta_j}\,\left|\overline{\theta_j}\right\rangle\,|1\rangle+\underbrace{\sum_j\left(\sum_{\substack{x=0\\x\neq\overline{\theta_j}}}^{\theta-1}\sum_{k=0}^{2^n-1}\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{2\,\mathrm{i}\,\pi\,k}{2^n}\,\left(x-\overline{\theta_j}\right)}\,\mathrm{e}^{2\,\mathrm{i}\,\pi\,k\,\delta_j}\,|x\rangle\,|1\rangle+\sum_{\substack{x=\theta\\x\neq\overline{\theta_j}}}^{2^n-1}\sum_{k=0}^{2^n-1}\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{2\,\mathrm{i}\,\pi\,k}{2^n}\,\left(x-\overline{\theta_j}\right)}\,\mathrm{e}^{2\,\mathrm{i}\,\pi\,k\,\delta_j}\,|x\rangle\,|0\rangle\right)}_{\text{Noise}}\right]\,.$$

The problem now is that I don't see how the uncomputation of the QPE will affect this state. My guess is that if I assume that the amplitude of the noise is low, then I can just ignore it, and this will not affect my results. But how can I prove it? How can I quantitize this error?

Comment: I think there shouldn't be $k$ index, instead, there should be only $j$ indexes, am I right? Also, I guess, after measurement, we should obtain $|v_j \rangle |\theta_j \rangle$ without the sum.

Comment: The QPE algorithm itself does not include a measurement. If the QPE is being performed in isolation, then the last thing you do is to measure the outcome, but if you're using QPE as part of a larger algorithm, e.g. HHL, you don't have the measurement in there.

Comment: Can you explain more about this noise term that you're getting. As you said, you should also uncompute the QPE, and that disentangles the two registers so there shouldn't be any noise (at least if the $\theta_k$ are exactly of the form $2\pi x/2^n$ for integer $x$.

Comment: @DavitKhachatryan, the $k$ here merely represents that after the measurement is performed, you get $\theta_k$ after measuring the second register with probability $\left\|\alpha_k\right\|^2$. The state you get at the end is not entangled anymore.

Comment: @DaftWullie, I'll edit my post with my computations then! But indeed, my problem comes from the fact that I cannot assume that all the $2^n\,\theta_j$ are integers.

Comment: So in that case, yes, indeed, there will be some additional entanglement left behind which is very messy to deal with explicitly. Usually, there's some sort of technique that lets you give a bound on how much error there is. Often, that is supplemented by repeating the QPE on several different registers and effectively getting a majority vote on the $\theta_j$ values.

Comment: Concerning the majority vote, what you do is adding the qubits that have the same role (the first qubit in each QPE for instance) and average them? Or do you take some sort of $\max$ function?